# Location Permission not working on flutter InAppWebView for some sites

Tags: flutter

I have been using the flutter InAppWebView plugin (5.7.2+3) to load a webpage inside my Android App. The site, requests location access when loads. But in my app, it is not firing any event although I have used all recommended codes.

I have added all necessary manifest permissions in my **AndroidManifest.xml** file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

In the View, I have listened for Geo Permission Request like:

```
androidOnGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt:(InAppWebViewController controller,String origin) async {
    if(await requestPermission("location")){
        return Future.value(GeolocationPermissionShowPromptResponse(origin: origin, allow: true, retain: true));
    }else{
        return Future.value(GeolocationPermissionShowPromptResponse(origin: origin, allow: false, retain: false));
    }
}
```

Here is my requestpermission function:

```
Future<bool> requestPermission(String permission) async {
  late PermissionStatus status;
  if(permission == "storage"){
    status = await Permission.storage.request();
  }else if(permission == "camera"){
    status = await Permission.camera.request();
  }else if(permission == "microphone"){
    status = await Permission.microphone.request();
  }else if(permission == "location"){
    status = await Permission.location.request();
  }
  if (status.isGranted) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

The code works on almost every websites where location permission is required, but in some websites (i.e. https://savelocal.app/) the code does not request location permission. Though loading the site in android browser, it asks for location access.

I was expecting if there is any thing in which I can focus to solve the issue or any modification in the code.

Comment: Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76860351/flutter-inappwebview-geolocation-error) question, This fixed my issue.