# Flutter | inappwebview - GeoLocation Error

Tags: javascript, flutter, permissions, geolocation

I'm pretty new to building apps in Flutter but I've developed so far an app that has a fullscreen "inappwebview".

The page that it points to is a webpage that I also made using JavaScript that requests permission to use the Geolocation API. Namely, i've copied and pasted the JavaScript found here: https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation_error

My problem is, when I point my webview at the above URL, the geolocation works absolutely fine as intended... but when I point it to my web page (which is https:// might I add)... it says the user denied the permission request - even though I didn't - AND it's the same JS as that of the w3schools page.

The code for my Flutter App is as follows:

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  var status = await Permission.location.request();
  if (status.isGranted) {
    runApp(MyApp());
  } else {
    if (status.isPermanentlyDenied) {
      openAppSettings();
    }
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Fullscreen WebView App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: FullScreenWebView(),
    );
  }
}

class FullScreenWebView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: InAppWebView(
                initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(
                  url: Uri.parse(
                      'https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp'),
                ),
                initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
                  android: AndroidInAppWebViewOptions(
                    useWideViewPort: true,
                    geolocationEnabled: true,
                  ),
                  ios: IOSInAppWebViewOptions(
                    allowsInlineMediaPlayback: true,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I also have the following in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

I've spent the best part of a day pulling my hair out about this. Not even ChatGPT knows why. I'm hoping someone here can come to my rescue. I would greatly appreciate it.

If i've missed any information, or you'd like to know more, please let me know. I've done my best to be as descriptive as possible as I know lesser ones seem to get a negative response.

---

### EDIT

Here's the code for the web page that's doing the Geolocation request:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
div {display:grid; place-items:center; scale: 1.1;}
</style>

<body>
    <div>
    <p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>
    <button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    
    <button onclick="location.reload()">reload</button>
    </div>
    
    <script>
    var x = document.getElementById("demo");
    document.write("&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;"+document.URL)
    function getLocation() {
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, showError);
      } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
      }
    }
    
    function showPosition(position) {
      x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
      "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
    }
    
    function showError(error) {
      switch(error.code) {
        case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
          x.innerHTML = "User denied the request for Geolocation."
          break;
        case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
          x.innerHTML = "Location information is unavailable."
          break;
        case error.TIMEOUT:
          x.innerHTML = "The request to get user location timed out."
          break;
        case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
          x.innerHTML = "An unknown error occurred."
          break;
      }
    }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you add the GPS feature in the manifest? See here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element#permissions
`<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps">`

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the suggestion. I hadn't but after just adding it and rebuilding... it didn't work. That being said, the fact that the w3schools website worked even without that... but mine doesn't even though it's the same code just hosted elsewhere is confusing the heck out of me.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the description of the situation. I didn't realise that you were viewing the reference webpage _from the same app_. Then it must definitely be something about your webpage. You should post the relevant part of your webpage's code if it is the main suspect…

Comment: I've added it to the original post, thank you

Comment: You can get the same error message even right here on Stack Overflow, if you click on _Run code snippet_. It's not due to your Android manifest or Flutter code.

Comment: I noticed that too, but that same code - exactly as it appears above, works when i'm browsing to the page which is uploaded to my server in a standard desktop/mobile browser. It isn't until you either view it via my Flutter App, or as it stands, via StackOverflow, that it doesn't appear to work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254851/discussion-between-dan-wheeler-and-mauro-vanetti).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to resolve the issue, for anyone interested, here's what I did:

```
InAppWebView(
    initialUrlRequest:
        URLRequest(url: Uri.parse('https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp')),
    androidOnGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt:
        (InAppWebViewController controller, String origin) async {
    return GeolocationPermissionShowPromptResponse(
        origin: origin, allow: true, retain: true);
    },
    initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
        android: AndroidInAppWebViewOptions(
            useWideViewPort: true,
            geolocationEnabled: true,
        ),
        ios: IOSInAppWebViewOptions(
            allowsInlineMediaPlayback: true,
        ),
    ),
    androidOnPermissionRequest: (InAppWebViewController controller,
        String origin, List<String> resources) async {
    return PermissionRequestResponse(
        resources: resources,
        action: PermissionRequestResponseAction.GRANT);
})
```

Thanks to Mauro for the help though.